# error in xml file while writing it?

Tags: php, xml, yii

I am writing an XML file to a folder while writing a dot(.) gets append at the start of the XML tag due to which it throws me error while reading it.

```
$data = Yii::app()->CURL->run('http:// my ip address/project/API/getxml.php',FALSE,
        array(
            'id'=>'75'
            )
        );

        thefile= Yii::app()->basepath."/../xml/new_api_test.xml";
        $openedfile = fopen($thefile, "w");
        fwrite($openedfile, $data);
        fclose($openedfile);
```

Comment: yes..it run even write's the file..but the issue is that it appends a dot(.) at the start of the XML file.

Comment: Then you are looking at the wrong source code. Seriously. It also happens to me now and then.

Comment: It seems the dot comes from `$data` (there is nowhere else it could come from). If you hit that URL manually do you still get the dot in the output?

Comment: i did tried the same by hitting the URl but the xml seems to be fine and even get displayed in brower without any error nor their is any dot when inspected via source code.

Comment: try to echo data after it returned from curl, is there a dot? if so check `run()` function, maybe it adding dot somewhere inside?

Comment: thanx..!! the xml some how was getting encoded to some format due to which the dot or question mark was getting attached..

Comment: @user1045373 You should post your solution below and accept the answer.